# Problema con la altura de barra de navegación

Tags: html, css, css3

Estoy tratando de diseñar un dashboard, el problema es con el menu, el tamaño del menu quiero que se ponga en `height:100%` intenté varias formas de hacerlo, pero no tengo éxito.
Para poder ver mi el ejemplo en pantalla completa.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,800");
html {
  height: 100%; }

@media (min-height: 768px) {
  body {
    height: 100%; } }

#app {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Nunito, sans-serif;
  background: #2abbb9; }

#app .container,
#app .columns {
  height: 100%; }

#app .menu {
  height: 100%;
  background: red; }


.menu-list__main li {`introducir el código aquí`
  padding: 0.5rem 0; }
  .menu-list__main li .fas, .menu-list__main li .far {
    width: 35px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    padding-right: 0.9rem; }
  .menu-list__main li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    opacity: 0.6; }
  .menu-list__main li a.active {
    opacity: 1.0; }
  .menu-list__main li a:hover {
    background-color: inherit;
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 1.0; }

.menu-list__outlier {
  margin-top: 10.0rem; }

#app .dashboard {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f9fafb; }

.dashboard__content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto; }
  .dashboard__content .header {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 3.0rem; }
  .dashboard__content .row {
    margin: 1.0rem 0; }
  .dashboard__content .bottom-row {
    margin-bottom: 3.0rem; }



.flex-center, #app, .menu-list__profile, #app .dashboard {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; }

@media (max-width: 1216px) {
  .menu-list__profile {
    flex-direction: column; }
    .menu-list__profile .title {
      padding-top: 0.5rem; }
    .menu-list__profile .subtitle {
      padding-top: 0; }

  .media-content {
    text-align: center; }

  .card .card-content {
    padding: 1.0rem; }
  .card .card .title {
    font-size: 0.7rem; }
  .card .content {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem; } }
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #app .container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%; }

  .dashboard__content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; } }
@media (min-width: 720px) {
  .columns {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex; }

  .columns > .column.is-3 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: none;
    flex: none;
    width: 25%; } }
@media (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 840px) {
  .menu-list__profile .subtitle {
    font-size: 0.6rem; }

  .menu-list__main li .fas {
    font-size: 1.1rem !important; }

  .menu-list__main li a {
    font-size: .60rem !important; } }
@media (max-width: 720px) {
  #app .container {
    width: 100%; }

  .menu-list__main {
    display: none; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns is-gapless">
                <div class="column is-3">
                    <aside class="menu">
                        <ul class="menu-list">
                            <div class="menu-list__profile media">
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-5 font-color-white">Usuario</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-list__main is-uppercase has-text-left">
                                <li><a class="subtitle is-7">Opcion</a></li>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </aside>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="dashboard">
                        <p>Hola Mundo</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que intento hacer es que me ocupe todo el largo de la pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: talvez tratas de decir height:100% en lugar de heading:100%?

Comment: Si, gracias. :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes agregar en la hoja de estilos donde quieras que se vea la pantalla completa el código:

```css
height: 100vh;
```

Eso hará que ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla sin importar el tamaño de la misma.

Comment: te saludo y te doy la bienvenida, te comento tu respuesta aunque pudiera guiar al OP es de muy baja calidad pues no explicas el por que ni das un contexto mas amplio, te sugiero leer como responder [answer] y del mismo modo hagas el tour para que te familiarices con el sitio saludos [tour]

Comment: Gracias, funcionó de maravilla!

Comment: Hola ChristianDaza, aunque esta respuesta resuelve el problema de la pregunta, ha sido reportada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Deberías editarla para darle un formato algo diferente (tal y como está escrita ahora no pareces muy convencido de que vaya a funcionar) y añadir más información (¿por qué `vh` funciona y no `%`? ¿dónde iría el `height: 100vh` en el código de la pregunta?). Lee [answer] para más información y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y co ello ganar una nueva medalla).